# How do you prove that a set is empty?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Prove that $A=B \Rightarrow A \setminus B = \emptyset$ and $\Rightarrow B \setminus A = \emptyset$

Before I even start this proof, I don't even know how to prove that a set is empty.
For example if I want to prove $A = \emptyset$, can I do:

$\forall x: x\notin A$?

Comment: You know that A=B so you can substitute A for B and vice versa, making the statement trivial.

Comment: You can also derive a contradiction from $\exists x: x\in A\setminus B$ to show that $A\setminus B$ is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose by contradiction that $\exists x\in A \setminus B$

Therefore we know $x\in A $ $ \land $ $x \notin B$ which is a contradiction because $A=B$.

To prove the second statement, use the exact same proof.